# Customize prestashop web service

Tags: json, web-services, rest, crud, prestashop-1.6

I want to customize Prestashop web service for my own usage but I don't know how and I can't find any tutorial. I have a mobile application that want to retrieve data from website but the default web service is useless.

For example I want the list of categories (in a language) with they're pictures but It seems I should call two different service to retrieve categories and images separately.

Assume I want to have a JSON array of categories that a category is a JSON object that have these fields `{id,title,imageUrl}` but It seems I should get `{id,title}` with a method and after that I can get images on by one by another method!

I couldn't find any guide for extending or customizing web service in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but:

Prestashop version requier : > 1.6

If you want to customize a web service and return specific fields with a JSON format output. You need to do it this way:

**First**

In override :

- Create a class : **myClassForWs** that extends **myClassCore**
- Override **WebserviceRequest** in  **webservice/WebserviceRequest.php**
- In **webservice/WebserviceRequest.php** : Add myClassForWs to
  ressources:

  ```
  public static function getResources()
  {
      $resources = parent::getResources();
      $resources['myClassForWs'] = array('description' => 'The class','class' => 'myClassForWs');
      ksort($resources);
      return $resources;
  }
  ```

  }
- In **myClassForWs** : redefine $webserviceParameters and $definition with the fields you need:

  ```
  protected $definition = array(
      'table' => 'category',
      'primary' => 'id_category',
      'multilang' => true,
      'multilang_shop' => true,
      'fields' => array(
          'name' =>array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCatalogName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
          'link_rewrite' =>array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isLinkRewrite', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
          'description' =>array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml'),
      ),
  );

  protected $webserviceParameters = array(
      'objectsNodeName' =>'categories',
      'hidden_fields'=>array('nleft', 'nright', 'groupBox'),
      'fields' => array(
          'level_depth' => array('setter' => false),
      ),
      'associations' => array(
          'images' => array(
          'resource' => 'image',
          'fields' => array('id' => array())
      ),
      ),
  );
  ```

**Then**

Go in your admin tab :

- in performance : **clear cache**
- in advanced settings > Web service: active a api Key and set **myClassForWs** for this key

**Finally**

Access to your web service with url :

```
my.prestashop/api/myClassForWs/{id_class}?output_format=**JSON**
```

And it returns your datas

I hope it helps.